# How to test my application is UNICODE Compatible or not?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode

I apologise if it is a silly question..I recently developed an application in windows with C and WinApi. I am in need to check whether application is UNICODE compatible or not. How can I test my machine? Is there any procedure followed to check UNICODE Compatibility. More over I dont have a chinese language machine or any other languages. I want this test to be done in my machine in which language is by default English.

Please provide some links if possible or a detailed procedure.

Comment: My application is working for all the versions of windows starting from xp to windows 7 (including 32 and 64 bit)

Comment: Thad fact doesn't change much.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: that said, it is sometimes helpful to have a "Chinese language machine", or at least a "Turkish language machine". Without testing the code in different locales, there are some issues you don't catch. Just for a tiny example, not Unicode-related: you can test all you like that the value `1.0` prints as `"1.0"` in the user's locale, but if you never set the user's locale to anything in Europe then you won't see it print as `"1,0"` instead. So your tests won't notice if your code has erroneously relied on a particular decimal separator.

Comment: @SteveJessop Right. Locales are also settable, though.

Comment: @Alexey: yeah, I'm not sure what the questioner considers "not Chinese-language" about the *machine*. Half of it was probably made in China, so it's not an "English" machine either ;-) Windows has separate locales for non-Unicode and language packs to change the language of Windows "properly", not all versions support packs. Even different localized text from the OS can break your program, if you've done something daft with a dialog box. But I guess I'm going beyond the simple question of whether the program is Unicode-aware, to whether it's fit for international use: a stronger requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question. On Windows platform this is challenging indeed, because there are many different encodings and code pages supported and one can mix between them.

What I usually do is test the application on input which is a mix of two non-ASCII languages, such as a filename which is a mix of Russian and Hebrew letters, and see that the application is able to open this file, etc. You can copy this: `"שלום привет hello"` and see how it works for this kind of input.

Because we have two languages here, it is not possible to support with an ANSI codepage, so there will be no this kind of a bug, which is the most common.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. My application doesnt get any input from the user. But, the use of paths (folder names, file names) are more. I want to know if there is a way to test this case, by giving some UNICODE kind of path names. Can you give me some exmaples to test the paths.

Comment: Pavel gave you the answer.  Copy his example file name.  Then create a new folder on your computer and paste that example for the new folder name.  If needed, create a new file in the folder and paste that example for the filename too.  Now run your program on this newly created folder :)